# Kivy Builder - Dynamic Button on_press

Tags: python, kivy

I have been creating an application using kivy. Within my app, I have a button that reads from a directory, and adds a button for each file in the directory, to a popup widget.

The code to generate the buttons works nicely, and no issues there. My issue is when I assign an on_press or other event, to fire a method inside my main.py.

main.py snippet;

```
    class Container(BoxLayout):
        container=ObjectProperty(None)
        SelectGamePopup = Popup(title='Start A New Game', size_hint=(None, None))
        ...
        def newGame(self):
            BlankLayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            BlankGrid = GridLayout(cols=3, size_hint_y=7)
            DismissButton = Button(text='Back', size_hint_y=1)
            DismissButton.bind(on_press=Container.SelectGamePopup.dismiss)

            for files in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Games')):
                addFile = files.rstrip('.ini')
                BlankGrid.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
Button:
text:''' + "\"" + addFile + "\"" + '''
on_press: root.gameChooser(''' + "\"" + addFile + "\"" + ''')
'''))

            BlankLayout.add_widget(BlankGrid)
            BlankLayout.add_widget(DismissButton)

            Container.SelectGamePopup.content = BlankLayout
            Container.SelectGamePopup.size=(self.container.width - 10, self.container.height - 10)
            Container.SelectGamePopup.open()

        def gameChooser(self, game):
            Container.SelectGamePopup.dismiss
            print(game)
```

The issue lies with `on_press: root.gameChooser(''' + "\"" + addFile + "\"" + ''')`. The error thrown back is;
`AttributeError: 'Button:' object has no attribute 'gameChooser'`.

How do I get this dynamically created button to call the function I desire, as well as passing the dynamic name to that function?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the button in python language and bind with on_press and send argument using partial

```
from functools import partial 
class Container(BoxLayout):
    container=ObjectProperty(None)
    SelectGamePopup = Popup(title='Start A New Game', size_hint=(None, None))
    ...
    def newGame(self):
        BlankLayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        BlankGrid = GridLayout(cols=3, size_hint_y=7)
        DismissButton = Button(text='Back', size_hint_y=1)
        DismissButton.bind(on_press=Container.SelectGamePopup.dismiss)

        for files in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Games')):
            addFile = files.rstrip('.ini')
            # normal button
            MydynamicButton = Button(text=addFile)
            # bind and send 
            MydinamicButton.bind(on_press = partial(self.gamechooser ,addFile)) #use partila to send argument to callback
            BlankGrid.add_widget(MydinamicButton)


        BlankLayout.add_widget(BlankGrid)
        BlankLayout.add_widget(DismissButton)

        Container.SelectGamePopup.content = BlankLayout
        Container.SelectGamePopup.size=(self.container.width - 10, self.container.height - 10)
        Container.SelectGamePopup.open()
    # you can use *args to get all extra argument that comes with on_press in a list
    def gameChooser(self, game ,*args):
        Container.SelectGamePopup.dismiss
        print(game)
```